# Can't install package openssl

Tags: r, openssl, r-package

While trying to install devtools, I supposedly upgrade my R version through brew (don't know how. Maybe I entered some whole installer instructions).

Devtools couldn't be installed correctly and now I ended with no packages installed at all to use with my R (new) version.

In the middle, I updated XCode from the AppStore.

When I try to reinstall all the packages, I stumble across the installation of openssl with a non-zero exit status.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openssl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_free'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/openssl’
```

This is my R version:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin22.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin22.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin22.4.0        
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          3.1                         
year           2023                        
month          06                          
day            16                          
svn rev        84548                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
nickname       Beagle Scouts
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it was difficult to find a smooth process to uninstall R version 4.3.1, because this conf has been up and running for quite a long time (migrated to this Mac from a previous intel processor), digging into /usr/local/lib/R/version-number/site-library/, I found there all the installed packages for the previous version.
So my first try was to just copy the "problematic" package to the new version.

I copied openssl from version 4.2 (which was the previous working version) to the  directory for the 4.3, as shown below:

```
juan:bin/ $ cd /usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library                                      [11:55:18]
juan:site-library/ $ cp -R /usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/openssl .
```

Then load the openssl package via `library(openssl)` and worked just fine.
This didn't fix the installation of devtools via install.packages(). When trying to install that package (devtools), it still tries to re-install openssl package because devtools is requiring openssl >= 2.0.3 and the current installed version was 2.0.0
But at least fixed my particular problem where R has been updated to 4.3.1 and couldn't install any package to make my scripts work.

The next stage is uninstall everything and restart with a clean conf.

Comment: You say that this is a Mac, but these paths do not look like a proper R macOS installation. Did you use Homebrew to install R? If so, I strongly recommend uninstalling R completely and using the official installer or [rig](https://github.com/r-lib/rig) to reinstall R. This will avoid a lot of issues, and chances are it will fix your current issue too.

Comment: It is a Mac. Absolutely sure about that. The conf was migrated from a previous one with intel processor. Does rig work with M1 processors? will give it a try (have troubles installing devtools though). I certainly need to clean up this...

Comment: rig works just fine with ARM processors. But when migrating configurations you need to be careful to make sure that there are no compatibilities. I suggest starting with a clean slate and only slowly building up a new configuration piece by piece.

Comment: You're right about that. Need to get two days off work to delete and start with a new conf.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).